# Perform Multiplication and Division in Moment.Js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to divide the value of duration by 9 and then multiply it by 10. newduration is currently not being returned in seconds.
For instance, duration returns 299988000
while newduration returns 311176. How can i fix this?

```js
let start = 1960
let end = 1979
let duration = moment(end.toString()).unix() - moment(start.toString()).unix();
let newduration = ((duration/9) * 10).unix();
let newvalue = moment(end.toString()).subtract(newduration, "second");

console.log(duration, newduration, newvalue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't add that `.unix()` at the end of the duration-based calculation: duration is just a plain number. If you run your code (I've updated it to a snippet) you'll see that you get an error on that `.unix()` call. Remove that, and things will work as expected. Except for the part where the assumption that subtracting the difference in seconds from 00:00 on January first, 1979, will get you to 1960. Because without fully qualified start and end datetimes (as in, a time, a date, _and_ a timezone) that is very much not guaranteed =)

Comment: @Mike When I remove the .unix(), I get an error that says ```not a type of integer```. As I mentioned,  newduration returns 311176, but I want it to return something like 311176000

Comment: if you run the snippet with that `.unix()` call removed from `newduration = ...`, you'll notice it runs without error and console logs `599616000 666240000 "1957-11-21T05:20:00.000Z"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are looking for subtracting difference of your end and start which you returned as seconds, then this might help:

```js
    let start = 1977
    let end = 1985
    
    let duration = moment().year(end).unix()- moment().year(start).unix();
    let newduration = (duration/9) * 10;
    let newvalue = moment().year(end).subtract(newduration, "second");
    console.log(newvalue.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```